# Using SSVNC and SSH - am I safe?

Tags: vnc, vncviewer

I connect from one computer to another (both Ubuntu) via SSH using an SSH-key. Now I also installed a vnc server on one of them (`vnc4server`) and use ssvnc (downloaded from the software center) to connect. In the viewer options, I choose "Use SSH" but nothing else. (except for entering a vnc password)

Is that a safe way of working remotely? Is the transferred data (screen information, keyboard input, etc) encrypted? If not, what is the SSH-option for?

Sorry about not knowing about anything. I am just wondering whether I really need to go through all of [What's the best way to secure a Teamviewer/X11/VNC connection?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9123/whats-the-best-way-to-secure-a-teamviewer-x11-vnc-connection)

Comment: So is this already a SSH tunnel, the usage of which is suggested in so many other questions, or is perhaps only the initial connection encrypted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The short answer is, yes!

When `SSH` is used with `VNC`, it means first an `SSH` connection is established, then the `VNC` connection is "tunneled" through the `SSH` connection.

Having said that I have never used `ssvnc`, but the name seems to suggest it uses SSH and VNC protocols. Then it stands to reason that it uses SSH tunnelling.

I use [`Remmina`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/remmina/), a versatile remote connection tool that allows using various protocols, including `SSH`, `VNC` and both of them together.

The question and answer you linked has some good advice. You can create an `SSH` tunnel on your own, and then use `VNC` separately to connect to 127.0.0.1. But remmina and presumably ssvnc will do all that for you.

Hope this helps